# Reading text file and sending mails to outlook using Python

Tags: python, outlook, office-automation, com-automation

I am reading .txt file in Python code and I should get the same mail body what I have in my text file.
It is working fine but hyperlinks not displayed in my outlook email, it displays only as text in  outlook email.

Below is the code:

```py
Mail_Content = open("MailBody.txt","r")
    Read_Content = Mail_Content.read()
```

In the text file , passing content like this for hyperlink:

```html
<a href="link">linkname</a>,'html'
```

Please help me out, I am trying to fix this from last two days.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you really need to show the code that sets the message body. Secondly, make sure you set the `MailItem.HTMLBody` rather than the plaintext `MailItem.Body`.

Comment: Mail_Content = open("MailBody.txt","r")
            Read_Content = Mail_Content.read()
            newMail.HTMLBody = Read_Content.format(plan date=Plan Date)

Comment: Below is MailBody.txt file .

Comment: Hello All,

Please find the workload report.

You can update it in sprint {plan date}.

For anything you can follow below link.


<u <a href="https://www.codecademy.com/catalog/language/python">Codeacademy</a>,'html'

Comment: If I use MailItem.HTMLBody, link displays properly in outlook email, but Email format is not proper

Comment: please see my above comments.    Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by " Email format is not proper"?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `BodyFormat` property is set up correctly before setting the `HTMLBody` property in the code, for example, here is a VBA sample which shows how to set up it properly:

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
 'Creates a new email item and modifies its properties. 
 Dim objMail As MailItem 
 'Create mail item 
 Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 With objMail 
   'Set body format to HTML 
   .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
   .HTMLBody = "<HTML><H2>The body of this message will appear in HTML.</H2><BODY>Type the message text here. </BODY></HTML>" 
   .Display 
 End With 
End Sub
```